Maven Mojo Execution Fails in GitHub Actions with `OutOfScopeException`
I have a Maven plugin with a Mojo (called DownloadDepsMojo) that manually downloads and unpacks a Maven dependency. It calls the following piece of code somewhere inside the exec method:
// ...
MojoExecutor.executeMojo(
    MojoExecutor.plugin(
        MojoExecutor.groupId("org.apache.maven.plugins"),
        MojoExecutor.artifactId("maven-dependency-plugin")
    ),
    MojoExecutor.goal("unpack"),
    MojoExecutor.configuration(
        MojoExecutor.element(
            "artifactItems",
            MojoExecutor.element(
                "artifactItem",
                MojoExecutor.element("groupId", dep.getGroupId()),
                MojoExecutor.element("artifactId", dep.getArtifactId()),
                MojoExecutor.element("classifier", dep.getClassifier()),
                MojoExecutor.element("version", dep.getVersion()),
                MojoExecutor.element("outputDirectory", path.toString())
            )
        )
    ),
    MojoExecutor.executionEnvironment(
        this.project,
        this.session,
        this.manager
    )
);
// ...

In short: this code calls the "unpack" goal to download the dependency dep and unpack it into the folder specified by the path path. MojoExecutor is a class from this library: https://github.com/mojo-executor/mojo-executor.
Running this DownloadDepsMojo locally on my computer works correctly. However, if I try to run the same code in the GitHub workflow, it results in an error:
Warning:  Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error in custom provider, com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: Cannot access Key[type=org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession, annotation=[none]] outside of a scoping block
  at org.apache.maven.session.scope.internal.SessionScopeModule.configure(SessionScopeModule.java:64) (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.apache.maven.session.scope.internal.SessionScopeModule)
  while locating org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugins.dependency.fromConfiguration.UnpackMojo

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo (MojoExecutor.java:120)
    at org.eolang.maven.Central.accept (Central.java:91)
    at org.eolang.maven.Central.accept (Central.java:42)
    at org.eolang.maven.DownloadDepsMojo.exec (DownloadDepsMojo.java:67)
    at org.eolang.maven.SafeMojo.lambda$execWithTimeout$4 (SafeMojo.java:349)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: com.google.inject.OutOfScopeException: Cannot access Key[type=org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession, annotation=[none]] outside of a scoping block
    at org.apache.maven.session.scope.internal.SessionScope$2.get (SessionScope.java:145)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:39)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusRequirements$RequirementProvider.get (PlexusRequirements.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.ProvidedPropertyBinding.injectProperty (ProvidedPropertyBinding.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanInjector.injectMembers (BeanInjector.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.injectMembers (MembersInjectorImpl.java:160)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision (ConstructorInjector.java:124)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000 (ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call (ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct (ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get (ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call (ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision (ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet (ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get (InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get (Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue (LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue (LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup (DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo (DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.twdata.maven.mojoexecutor.MojoExecutor.executeMojo (MojoExecutor.java:120)
    at org.eolang.maven.Central.accept (Central.java:91)
    at org.eolang.maven.Central.accept (Central.java:42)
    at org.eolang.maven.DownloadDepsMojo.exec (DownloadDepsMojo.java:67)
    at org.eolang.maven.SafeMojo.lambda$execWithTimeout$4 (SafeMojo.java:349)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1623)
Error:  Unable to execute mojo
Error:  Unable to load the mojo 'unpack' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.7.1'
Error:  Cannot access Key[type=org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession, annotation=[none]] outside of a scoping block
Error:  'org.eolang.maven.DownloadDepsMojo@7aa7e8db' execution failed
Error:  Unable to execute mojo
Error:  Unable to load the mojo 'unpack' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.7.1'
Error:  Cannot access Key[type=org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession, annotation=[none]] outside of a scoping block

That's how (simplified) workflow file looks like:
name: mvn
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
concurrency:
  group: mvn-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
jobs:
  mvn:
    name: mvn
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ ubuntu-20.04, windows-2022, macos-12 ]
        java: [ 11, 20 ]
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    env:
      CONVERT_PATH: /tmp/antlr4-to-bnf-converter
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v4
        with:
          distribution: 'temurin'
          java-version: ${{ matrix.java }}
      - uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ~/.m2/repository
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-jdk-${{ matrix.java }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-jdk-${{ matrix.java }}-maven-
      - run: mvn clean install -Pqulice --errors --batch-mode

I'm not sure, but I guess the problem is that there is something missing in the workflow environment.
There was some issues with the similar errors (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200272, https://github.com/gitflow-incremental-builder/gitflow-incremental-builder/issues/91), but I have not found how to relate them to my problem.
Is the problem with my github workflow environment? How can I fix this problem so that the workflow works correctly, like on my local computer?
Upd:
When I manually set version for maven-dependency-plugin to 2.0 it just worked fine on CI:
//...
MojoExecutor.executeMojo(
    MojoExecutor.plugin(
        MojoExecutor.groupId("org.apache.maven.plugins"),
        MojoExecutor.artifactId("maven-dependency-plugin"),
        MojoExecutor.version("2.0") // here!
    ),
    //...
);
//...

However, if I set this version to 3.7.1 or even 3.7.0 manually it didn't work on CI. But, locally on computer still works fine. I can't understand what is the reason for this behavior. Does anyone have an idea?
Also I still want to not specify version manually and use latest. So is there any adequate solution? It looks like the problem is really with CI.

Why are you usuing mojoExecutor ? Why not using plain Maven? DownloadDepsMojo there is a default which done by maven automatically if you define them in your pom file the deps are downloaded automatically by Maven itself
